# My asynchronous decorator keeps on returning a NoneType error

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

I'm trying to code a socket server on my raspberry pi. I'm trying to use a decorator to connect a client to a server(which will be my raspberry pi). But my code for it is keeping on throwing a NoneType error. I'm a bit new to asynchronous decorators, and need some help on them. Can you please see where my error is coming from, and please correct my code a bit? I will list my code and the error messages down below.

My error message:

```py
C:\Users\####\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/#####/Desktop/autorank/server/client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/#####/Desktop/autorank/server/client.py", line 5, in <module>
    @client.connection(("192.168.0.11", 56500))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

My client code for the package:

```
import socket, asyncio

class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = None
        self.data = None

    def connection(self, addr):
        """An asynchronous decorator for any server mainloop. Just decorate it with this and add a Client parameter."""

        def wrapper1(func):
            async def wrapper2(*args):
                self.connect(addr)
                await func(self)
                self.close_conn()
                return await func(self)
            return wrapper2

    async def connect(self, addr):
        """Connects to the desired server. You can make a server mainloop with the connection decorator."""

        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.connect(addr)

        self.addr = addr

        print(f"Connected to {addr}")

    async def close_conn(self):
        """Closes connection with the address connected to."""

        self.s.close()

        print(f"Disconnected from {self.addr}")
        del self.addr

    async def send_bytes(self, bytes_data):
        """Sends bytedata through a pipe to connected address"""

        self.s.sendall(bytes_data)

        print(f"Sent {bytes_data.decode()} in bytedata format to {self.addr}")

    async def recv(self, buf_size):
        """Recieves data from a server in bytedata format"""

        self.data = self.s.recv(buf_size)
```

And finally, my main.py:

```
import asyncserver

client = asyncserver.Client()

@client.connection(("192.168.0.11", 56500))
def mainloop(cli):
    cli.send_bytes(b'Hello!!')
    cli.recv(1024)
    print(cli.data.decode())
```

Please say if I should improve my question, and any answers are appreciated!

Comment: Looking at this code again, it is quite incorrect because it uses blocking sockets inside an asyncio event loop. For example, your `send_bytes()` coroutine will block the whole event loop while waiting for the peer to accept the bytes. This is a serious flaw which will cause other asyncio code to malfunction by not being parallelizable. You should use [`asyncio.open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) instead, store the stream objects it returns, and work with those.

Comment: Is it OK if you can explain more? I was trying to find a good asyncio server tutorial, but couldn't find one! I'd appreciate if you could send a link to an asyncio server tutorial, but anything else is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know of a server tutorial, but the [echo server example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#tcp-echo-server-using-streams) in the documentation is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connection` decorator correctly defines `wrapper1`, but fails to return it. It implicitly returns `None`, and that's what gets used as `mainloop` at top-level, resulting in the error.

Note that `wrapper2` *awaits* `func(self)`, which might lead to another error, about `None` not being awaitable. If you plan to await the function you decorate, you should either make it async (`async def mainloop(cli): ...`) or have it return an awaitable object.

Finally, `wrapper2` shouldn't accept arbitrary `*args` if it will not use them. That will cause something like `mainloop(1, 2, 3)` to appear to work while ignoring the arguments. Normally the point of a wrapper accepting `*args` is to *forward* them to the wrapped function. If you don't want or need that, just make the `wrapper2` accept no arguments.